# Sum of Bernoulli distributed variables

Tags: random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $N, X1, X2,...$ be independent stochastic variables where $N\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ and $X_i\sim Bernoulli(p)$ for $i = 1, 2,...$, with $\lambda>0$ & $0<p<1$.
The Compound Poisson variable $X$ is given by
\begin{equation}
  X=\sum_{j=1}^{N}X_j
 \end{equation}

**Assignment:** Find the distribution for $X$.

**Attempted Solution**: My reasoning is as follows

Each of the variables $X_j$ may assume values $x=1$ or $x=0$ with respective probabilities $p$ and $1-p$. This way the variable $X$ counts the number of "succesful" attempts, up to $N$ trials.

I think the chance to get $P(X=k)=P\left(\sum_{j=1}^{N}X_j=k\right)$ should be the chance for $P\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j=k\right)$ multiplied by $P(N=n)$. That is; it's the chance to get $k$ successes in $n$ attempts, multiplied by the chance to have those $n$ tries.

So this leads me to
\begin{align}
P(X=x) &= P\left(\{N=n\}\cap \left\{\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j=k\right\}\right)\\
       &= P(N=n)\cdot P\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j = k\right) \text{Because they're independent}\\
\end{align}

Then I use the fact that a sum of (indepedent, parameter $p$) Bernoulli trials will follow a Binomial distribution. Thus
\begin{align}
P(X=x) &= \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!} \cdot (_{k}^{n})p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
       &= \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!} \cdot \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
       &= \frac{e^{-\lambda}p^k\lambda^n}{k!} \cdot \frac{(1-p)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
\end{align}
Where I used the fact that $N\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ to find $P(N=n)$.

Thus concluding
$$P_X(x) =  
\begin{cases}
 \frac{e^{-\lambda}p^k\lambda^n}{k!}\cdot\frac{(1-p)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} & \text{for }k=1,2,3,...\\
 0     & \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I am, however, convinced I've gotten something wrong. Namely the fact that $n$ still shows up in the expression, though I can't quite tell what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went the right away! But you have to consider all cases of $n\geq k$. Let $A_n=\{N=n\}$ for all $n\geq 0$. Observe that all $A_n$'s are disjoint and their union is $\Omega$. Also, observe that $P(\{X=k\}\cap A_n)=0$ when $n<k$. Now fix $k\geq 0$ and write

\begin{align}
P(X=k)&=P\bigl(\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\{X=k\}\cap A_n\bigr)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(\{X=k\}\cap A_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}P(X=k\ |\ N=n)\cdot P(N=n)
\end{align}

Now $P(X=k\ |\ N=n)={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ and $P(N=n)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$. Putting all together, for $k\geq 0$

$$P(X=k)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$$